# UITableView ignoring method call only on iPhone 5

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios6, iphone-5, nsindexpath

This seems strange, and maybe I don't have the issue fully nailed, but I am perplexed.

In my app, I present a UITableView modally in a VC and have created a custom init method to additionally send an index path for where the table should scroll to.

in ViewDidLoad, the following call is executed correctly on iPhone4S and earlier, but ignored on iPhone5:

```
[table scrollToRowAtIndexPath:iP atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
```

Any suggestions? Have I made any false assumptions?

Comment: do they have the same ios version?

Comment: Sounds like maybe the culprit is elsewhere. Check to make sure `table` isn't nil would be my first guess but I'm not sure.

Comment: same ios version, table is fine

Comment: Are you using autolayout or any autoresizing masks? Does it also ignore `scrollToNearestSelectedRowAtScrollPosition:animated:`?

Comment: auto sizing handles just fine. Haven't checked the other method.. but that's not the method I would prefer to use

Comment: If instead of doing it in `viewDidLoad` you do something like `[self performSelector:@selector(setScrollPosition) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];` and have a method `setScrollPosition` that makes the call you've given, does that make any difference?

Comment: good advice Tommy, i'll try it when I get a moment and get back to you.